# Transform an inexact differential into an exact differential using an integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There're answered questions here about what I'm asking; however, I didn't study differential equations yet, and those answers use technics to solve differential equations. But my teacher, knowing that, asked me to do this:

> Determine a function $u(x,y)$, such that, the differential $(x³ + x + y)u(x,y)dx - xu(x,y)dy$ be exact, and specify a potential for that differential. ($u$ is called an integrating factor for that differential)

I tried to use the assumption that

$$\begin{cases} \dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} = (x³ + x + y)u(x,y) \\ \dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} = - xu(x,y) \end{cases}$$

but I came to this differential equation:

$$\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y} (x³ + x + y) + \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x} x = -2u(x,y)$$

and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried $u(x,y)=u(x)$
Then got this

$$u(x)=-(u+xu') $$
$$\int \frac {du}{u}=-2\int \frac {dx}x$$
$$\implies u(x)=\frac 1 {x^2}$$

$$(x³ + x + y)u(x)dx - xu(x)dy$$
You have that :
$$\partial_y \left (\frac {x³ + x + y}{x^2} \right )= \partial_x \left (-\frac 1x \right )$$

Answer (score 0):

Just staring onto the equation I noticed that it would be simpler if $u(x,y)$ was constant in $y$.

That assumption will lead you to the ODE of Euler type.